# Creating a code that removes comment in C Preprocessor Style

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write a code that removes comment from a given file [C-Style].

The code that I have written for the function to remove comment is as below. I have passed the source file content in char *copy.

```
 char *remove_comment(char *copy) //if blank file
    {
    int length = strlen(copy);
    int i,j;

for(i=0; i<length; i++)

  {
        j=i;
        if(copy[j++]=='/')
        {
            if((copy[j]!='\0') &&  (copy[j]=='/')) //single line comment
            {
            while((copy[j]!='\0') && ((copy[j]!='\n') || ((copy[j]!='/') && (copy[j+1]!='/'))));

            if(copy[j]!='\0') j++; // Safety: INC beyond NULL would give unpredictable results
            memmove(copy[i],copy[j],length-j); //replace comments
            }

/*
                else if((copy[j]!='\0') || (copy[j]=='*')) //multi line comment
                { //later
                }
*/
printf("%s",copy);
        }
  }
return copy;
}
```

The code seems to be not doing what I expected. Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happened to the indentation of this code?

Comment: `memmove(copy[i],copy[j],length-j);` : type of `copy[i]` is `char`. not address of object.

Comment: Also, you're shortening the string without updating `length`.

Comment: And `((copy[j]!='/') && (copy[j+1]!='/'))` seems to be redundant for `//` comments (which are actually C++-style BTW).

Comment: `while((copy[j]!='\0') && ((copy[j]!='\n') || ((copy[j]!='/') && (copy[j+1]!='/'))));` this loop doesn't do anything but check requirements.

Comment: @Doherty Though in your code you are using a `char *copy`, the explanation states "a given file [C-Style]". Do you need the solution to be in C? I think for other languages it would be a one-liner. I personally would do it in sed, for the fun of it. Others probably would recommend awk. In perl it would still be quite easy, not a one-liner though. If other languages are OK, then keep the tag "c" (needed for understanding, even if not for solution) and add other tags, those which you would like.